# My user got deleted unistalling python3.6

Tags: python, login

I'm very new to Ubuntu 18.04. I wanted to uninstall python 3 using sudo apt-get remove python3. While uninstalling, some other programs such as chrome, firefox and ubuntu store started dissapearing. I thought it was strange, but that I could reinstall them as soon as it finished. As it was taking long, I locked (using this button) the screen and left for a while. When I returned and tried to write my password it didn't let me, automatically deselecting the space to write the password and giving an error. I then rebooted the computer, as it didn't let me in, and unstead of showing the users, the screen shows "(computer name) login:".
If I write something then it asks "Password:". If I write my username (only user in my computer, also an administrator user) and then my password it returns "Login incorrect" and goes back to asking for an input. I've tried rebooting many times, searching for videos and found nothing, pressing random ctrl and alt keys and nothing has worked. I think my user got deleted somehow as before rebooting it didn't even let me write my password. I still don't know how this happened if python isn't even related to installing or users. Can you please help me?
(P.S1 : I don't even know what tag to write, sorry)
P.S2: I didn't set up the computer, so I have no knowledge on how that works.

Comment: Removing Python will break your system as you can see.  Unfortunately the only way to restore your system from this point is a complete reinstallation.  You cannot remove Python 2 or Python 3 from the system because a huge portion of the core of the system runs under Python.

Comment: I agree with Thomas Ward. Removing python3 also removes a lot of dependencies, many of them crucial to the system. Reinstall and in the future only remove package you installed yourself

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I do that? Edit: I still left python3.9 installed, that's why I deleted 3.6,  because I have a newer version.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 goes with Python 3.6, as shown [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3).  You somehow installed the latest version of Python thinking "the latest is best", but removing the version that goes with 18.04 breaks many things.  From this point forward, re-installing the entire operating system is the easiest solution.  Trying to undo what you did is fairly difficult, especially if you admit you're "new to Ubuntu".  I've used it for over 10 years and I would do a re-install...it's the easiest solution.

Comment: In case my reply isn't clear, that means going to the Ubuntu web site and follow the instructions to get a new installation and wipe everything on your computer.  Is there data on the system that you need?  Wiping it all is the easiest solution...

Comment: Thank you Ray. Still I can't do anything with my computer. When I start it instead of showing my username, there is a black screen which says (yellow is computer name): "Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS yellow tty1 (enter space) yellow login:" I don't know what to input, but no matter what that is then it says "Password:". If the input is my username and the password my password, it still gives an error, so I can't access my computer at all. //And  no, I don't have anything I need in it so I can wipe it.

Comment: Just in case the above isn't clear, my username is the only one and it is an administrator user.

Comment: @Unnamed That's why I said where you are now is at a point where you can only repair the problem with a reinstallation from scratch.  If you only had one user and it worked only with a single user, it's not going to work.  Assuming the computer's name is/was 'yellow' then you're out of options if you can't login.

Comment: Can you login to a text terminal?    If you can, you can resurrect your system by manually downloading & installing the required packages (esp `python3-minimal` however you'll have to limit yourself to using basic tools (`wget` `dpkg` etc & no user wrappers like apt/apt-get etc as they need python3 of the specific version the system came with working first). Your system logs will show what you removed & what to return, but start with python minimal packages to get `apt` & `apt-get` functional which makes it easier...  re-installation is faster usually.

Comment: Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas Ward pointed out, removing Python 2 or 3 entirely will completely break your system. Ubuntu relies on both of these for A LOT of the system that runs both at boot, while using and other times. Even reinstalling the Python version you removed will not work (as you cannot replace ALL the files that are removed).

You have two options:

-Boot into an Ubuntu live USB, and copy over the /usr, /home Python portions and other important folders that contain any Python related content. This doesn't often work.

-Completely reinstall Ubuntu, but back up all of your stuff before doing so.

Comment: Why can't they simply boot live USB, chroot and install Ubuntu-Desktop? Wouldn't Ubuntu-Desktop include all the python3 stuff? Sorry if it's a dumb question. I haven't been smart enough to delete Python and find out for myself...

Comment: It is not smart to delete python, don't do it, I have a problem now.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have deleted it by accident before by having a typo in one of my sudo commands, and I had to do a total reinstall. In theory what you say could work, but I have never tried so I cannot comment on it's reliability.